# Touch scrolling issue in Ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad

I want to stop scrolling for the whole document in ipad except allowing scroll for one div only.

So here is my code

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();           
});
```

//Which prevents the document scrolling

```
$('#disclaimer-box-inner').bind('touchmove', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now the div which I have a scrollbar is named as disclaimer-box-inner. I want to allow scroll on this div.

The end result is it stops the scrolling through out the screen but stops the scrolling for that div as well.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really get it... are there other elements that are overflowing as well..? Can you create a mock demo..?

Comment: Basically I want to remove the document scrolling on ipad but allow scroll for a single div.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using css instead of jquery?

Like this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3xdy0zyg/1/

Just give your body

```
position: fixed;
```

And give your div with the class .scroll

```
overflow-y: scroll;
position: absolute;
```

Now you can scroll in the div but you cant scroll the body.

Comment: It's about the document scrolling. All works fine in any desktop browser but only thing in ipad I want to remove scrolling event.

Comment: so you just want to remove scrolling from that div for ipads?